# Is there an efficent way to calculate a value in a numpy array based on its location in the array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'll ask my question using an example. Let's say I have two numpy arrays:

`A = [(1 2 3),(4,5,6)]`

`B=[(1 2 3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9]`

I wish to make a new numpy array S where each cell is calculated using its coordinates with respect to A and B. for example:
S_ij=exp((A's ith row)^T * (B's jth row))

Is there a way to do such a thing in numpy without using loops? Sorry if my question is a bit messy.

Thanks!

Comment: That looks just like a matrix product? Like, if `a` and `b` are the 2x3 and 3x3 arrays you show, it would be just `s = np.exp(a @ b.T)`...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. Do you mean something like: `S_12 = np.exp(A[1].T) * B[2]`?

Comment: The real calculation I need to make is a bit more complicated than this, this was simply an example as to what I'm trying to do.
The question is whether I can make a function f that I can apply on A and B such that when S=f(A,B), each of S's cells will be calculated based on its coordinates.
Meaning in the context of the given example: S11 will be e^(1+4+9), S12 will be e^(4+10+18), etc.

Comment: In your example `A` is (2,3) shape, `B` (3,3).  What's the shape of `S`?  `numpy` has a lot of operators and functions that take arrays as input.  You need to take some time to study the `numpy` basics, including a focus on `broadcasting`.  The trick to using `numpy` effectively is to think in terms of the whole-arrays, rather than focus on elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [138]: A = np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)                                                
In [139]: B = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
```

Using `broadcasting` we can take the rows of the 2 arrays:

```
In [140]: (A[:,None,:]*B[None,:,:]).shape                                                
Out[140]: (2, 3, 3)
In [141]: np.exp((A[:,None,:]*B[None,:,:]))                                              
Out[141]: 
array([[[2.71828183e+00, 5.45981500e+01, 8.10308393e+03],
        [5.45981500e+01, 2.20264658e+04, 6.56599691e+07],
        [1.09663316e+03, 8.88611052e+06, 5.32048241e+11]],

       [[5.45981500e+01, 2.20264658e+04, 6.56599691e+07],
        [8.88611052e+06, 7.20048993e+10, 4.31123155e+15],
        [1.44625706e+12, 2.35385267e+17, 2.83075330e+23]]])
```

`*` is elementwise; maybe you wanted `dot/matrix product, the sum on the last dim:

```
In [142]: np.sum((A[:,None,:]*B[None,:,:]),axis=-1).shape                                
Out[142]: (2, 3)
In [143]: np.exp(np.sum((A[:,None,:]*B[None,:,:]),axis=-1))                              
Out[143]: 
array([[1.20260428e+06, 7.89629602e+13, 5.18470553e+21],
       [7.89629602e+13, 2.75851345e+33, 9.63666567e+52]])
```

`einsum` is a handy tool for doing matrix product:

```
In [144]: np.exp(np.einsum('ij,kj->ik',A,B))                                             
Out[144]: 
array([[1.20260428e+06, 7.89629602e+13, 5.18470553e+21],
       [7.89629602e+13, 2.75851345e+33, 9.63666567e+52]])
```

or with the matrix product operator:

```
In [145]: np.exp(A@B.T)                                                                  
Out[145]: 
array([[1.20260428e+06, 7.89629602e+13, 5.18470553e+21],
       [7.89629602e+13, 2.75851345e+33, 9.63666567e+52]])
```